# How can I make the Acensor jQuery plugin use custom IDs for each section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, plugins

I am using the [Ascensor jQuery plugin](http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/) and I need to replace the default id naming system (`#house0`, `#house1`, `#house2`) with my own.

For example, instead of `#house0`, `#house1` it would be `#home`, `#contact` etc.

My idea revolves around using an array with my names and then replace the default values. Does somebody know how to implement this?

Comment: please please show some code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ascensor settings, under the parameter AscensorFloorName, enter your floor names divided by a space and then pipe.

As in:

```
$('#ascensorBuilding')
    .ascensor({
    AscensorName: 'ascensor',
    ChildType: 'section',
    AscensorFloorName: 'Home | Implementation | HTML | Jquery | CSS | Smartphone | Credits',
    Time: 1000,
    WindowsOn: 1,
    Direction: 'chocolate',
    AscensorMap: '2|1 & 2|2 & 3|2 & 2|3 & 2|4 & 1|4 & 2|5',
    Easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
    KeyNavigation: true,
    Queued: false,

});
```

Comment: heh, back in the day when I asked the question it was another version of ascensor. This new one simplifies bussiness by a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

As per [page 4 of Acensor’s documentation](http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/#house4), you can pass a configuration parameter `AscensorName` when you call `ascensor()`, and that will define the name used for its classes and ids.

So, I would guess you’d do this:

```
$('#home').ascensor({
    AscensorName:'home'
});
```

I’ve no experience with Ascensor though, so I could be entirely wrong.

Comment: Well, that only changes the name of the ascensor. From house0, house1 etc it will change it in home0, home1. I need distinct names (home, contact, blog etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
i = {
            AscensorName: "page",
            AscensorFloorName: null,
```

Find this in the Plugin where is Null put what u want